# How to replace a string of specific characters with sed command

Tags: linux

I want to use the sed command to delete some specific strings.

This is the file(tRNA.fa):

```
>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-1 (chrII.trna5-AlaAGC) chrII:4565386-4565457 (+) Ala (AGC) 72 bp Sc: 72.4
GGGGGTATAGCTCAGTGGTAGAGCGCTCCCTTAGCATGGGAGAGGgCTGGGGTTCAATTC
CCCATACCTCCA
>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-10 (chrX.trna261-AlaAGC) chrX:7378738-7378809 (-) Ala (AGC) 72 bp Sc: 72.4
GGGGGTATAGCTCAGTGGTAGAGCGCTCCCTTAGCATGGGAGAGGgCTGGGGTTCAATTC
CCCATACCTCCA
>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-11 (chrX.trna260-AlaAGC) chrX:7507245-7507316 (-) Ala (AGC) 72 bp Sc: 72.4
GGGGGTATAGCTCAGTGGTAGAGCGCTCCCTTAGCATGGGAGAGGgCTGGGGTTCAATTC
CCCATACCTCCA
```

I just want to keep “>tRNA-XXX-XXX-X-X”and the next line.

So,I tried to replace unnecessary information with sed command:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\).*[0-9]$//g' tRNA.fa
```

However,I deleted all the line starting with '>'.

The result I hope to get is:

```
>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-1 
GGGGGTATAGCTCAGTGGTAGAGCGCTCCCTTAGCATGGGAGAGGgCTGGGGTTCAATTC
CCCATACCTCCA
>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-10 
GGGGGTATAGCTCAGTGGTAGAGCGCTCCCTTAGCATGGGAGAGGgCTGGGGTTCAATTC
CCCATACCTCCA
>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-11 
GGGGGTATAGCTCAGTGGTAGAGCGCTCCCTTAGCATGGGAGAGGgCTGGGGTTCAATTC
CCCATACCTCCA
```

If you know how to replace it, please tell me,thank you.

Comment: `delete some specific strings` - so which one? You didn't specify.

Comment: After pasting, > and some \n are Invisible.

Comment: such as:>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-1 IItna5-AlaAGC II:4565386-4565457  Ala AGC 72 bp S: 724
GGGGGTGGGTTCAATTC
>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-10 Xtna261-AlaAGC X:7378738-7378809 - Ala AGC 72 bp S: 724
GGGGGTATAGCTCAG

Comment: that's why use [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Refresh you site, I've tried to reformat your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match a `(` don't escape it.

```
sed -i 's/(.*).*[0-9]$//g' tRNA.fa
```

But really the following is just enough to remove everything after `(`:

```
sed -i 's/(.*//' tRNA.fa
```

Note that you may also want `s/ (.*//` to remove that space before `(` too.

The `\(...\)` is used to group expression into a subgroup. It is most often used for back references, but may also be used for example as `\(abc\)*` - will search zero or more occurrences of the string `"abc"`.

[Here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) is a great sed introduction.

Comment: Thanks,but I tried this `sed -i 's/(.*//' tRNA.fa`.It just deleted (), did not delete the string.

Comment: "the string" - which string? ... [Can't replicate, it works](http://tpcg.io/kEEx37).

Comment: **>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-1 (chrII.trna5-AlaAGC) chrII:4565386-4565457 (+) Ala (AGC) 72 bp Sc: 72.4**,I want to get **>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-1**

Comment: use `sed -i 's/(.*//' tRNA.fa`,I get **>tRNA-Ala-AGC-1-1 IItna5-AlaAGC II:4565386-4565457  Ala AGC 72 bp S: 724**

Comment: Yes,`sed -i 's/(.*//' tRNA.fa`,I succeeded in the link, but the terminal did not succeed. However,`sed -i 's/(.*).*[0-9]$//g' tRNA.fa`,successful in the terminal, thank you!

Comment: Hm, probably you have a different version of sed, and your's match from the last `(`, not from the first `(`. Probably adding `g` flag to the end may solve the issue. Or you could `rev | sed 's/.*(//' | rev` as the last stand. Good luck.